# send a PDF for signature using In DocuSign api

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, docusignapi

In DocuSign C# api Can I send a PDF document in landscape for signature ?

Comment: Please specify a bit more.

Comment: there are examples on the site ? https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-get-signatures-on-a-document-New-DocuSign-Experience

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you have a PDF that is in portrait, you want it in landscape for signing.

**Option 1**, purely using the C# SDK:

1. Convert your PDF to landscape (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-generate-a-runtime-pdf-with-landscape-and-portrait-bo/) (using iTextSharp NuGet)
2. Send your new PDF to DocuSign using the C# eSignature SDK NuGet - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/EmbeddedSigningCeremony.cs

**Option 2**
,You can make a raw API call to rotate an page of any document using this endpoint:

```
PUT restapi/v2.1/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>/documents/<documentId>/pages/<pageNumber>/page_image
```

The JSON of the body is something like this to rotate right or left:

```
{"rotate":"right"}
```